# org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request - Sending JSON request via REST

Tags: java, json, apache, post

I am receiving an error org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request when I try to run this program.

Could you please help me understand where I should modify the code ?

I am using the following libraries
httpclient-4.4.1.jar
httpcore-4.4.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.2.jar

org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request

Here is the code :

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/key/demo-scaling/start");
    try {
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity("(\"variables\":{}, \"businessKey\" : \"AAA001\")");
        postRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);
        postRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(postRequest, responseHandler);
        System.out.println(responseBody);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/key/demo-  scaling/start"  why you have a spaces there before scaling/start? If you need there spaces, use %20 for that. THen you will have a valid url and right request :)

Comment: I have it correct in the program Hrabosch where I just checked it now.

Comment: Ok then you can try for example Postman extension for Chrome and try to call i manually.

Comment: From the postman its actually working but I have a requirement to call it via Java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this:

```
 HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/key/demo-scaling/start");
        StringEntity params =new StringEntity("variables={\"businessKey\":\"AAA001\"}");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        System.out.println(response);
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle Exceptions
    }
```

Use httpclientbuilder to get client (DefaultHttpClient -> Deprecated) and i am not sure if you have a valid JSON data, this is only my suggest.

Comment: if we want GET request is that just change the POST into GET and remove the parameters...?